# NextJS and Flask hosted on Vercel, No module named 'flask_migrate'

Tags: flask, vercel, next.js13

NextJS and Flask hosted on Vercel, No module named 'flask_migrate'

I am integrating flask into nextjs and get the following error when I host on vercel, it works fine in local host.

```
`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': 
No module named 'flask_migrate'
Traceback (most recent call last):`
```

Here is my requirements.txt file

here is a link to the repo https://github.com/mbron770/pychat.git

I tried changing version of werkzeug and flask many times but it didnt work

Comment: Can you run `pip list` in your venv and paste the output here?

Comment: here is the pip list, its long so Ill post it in separate comments
alembic               1.12.0
aniso8601             9.0.1
appnope               0.1.3
asttokens             2.2.1
backcall              0.2.0
blinker               1.6.2
certifi               2022.12.7
charset-normalizer    3.2.0
click                 8.1.7
colorama              0.4.6
cors                  1.0.1
decorator             5.1.1
distlib               0.3.7
exceptiongroup        1.1.3
executing             1.2.0
Faker                 19.2.0
filelock              3.12.2
Flask                 3.0.0

Comment: Flask-Cors            3.0.10
Flask-Migrate         4.0.5
Flask-RESTful         0.3.10
Flask-SQLAlchemy      3.1.1
future                0.18.3
gevent                23.9.1
greenlet              3.0.0
idna                  3.4
importlib-metadata    6.8.0
importlib-resources   6.1.0
ipdb                  0.13.13
ipython               8.16.1
itsdangerous          2.1.2
jedi                  0.19.1

Comment: Jinja2                3.1.2
Mako                  1.2.4
MarkupSafe            2.1.3
matplotlib-inline     0.1.6
numpy                 1.24.3
parso                 0.8.3
pexpect               4.8.0
pickleshare           0.7.5
pip                   23.2.1
pipenv                2023.4.29
platformdirs          3.9.1
prompt-toolkit        3.0.39
psycopg2              2.9.8
ptyprocess            0.7.0
pure-eval             0.2.2
Pygments              2.15.1
PySocks               1.7.1
python-dateutil       2.8.2

Comment: pytz                  2023.3.post1
requests              2.31.0
requests-file         1.5.1
setuptools            68.0.0
six                   1.16.0
SQLAlchemy            2.0.21
SQLAlchemy-serializer 1.4.1
stack-data            0.6.2
tabulate              0.9.0
tldextract            3.6.0
tomli                 2.0.1
traitlets             5.9.0
typing_extensions     4.7.1
urllib3               2.0.4
virtualenv            20.24.5
virtualenv-clone      0.5.7
wcwidth               0.2.6

Comment: Werkzeug              3.0.0
wheel                 0.41.0
whitenoise            6.5.0
zipp                  3.16.2
zope.event            5.0
zope.interface        6.0

Comment: Hello, please make so that relevant details are inserted in the body of the question rather than in comments.